# how do runas in vbscript and parse parameter SW_HIDE

Tags: batch-file, command-line, vbscript

I have to create a vbscript with runas and hide the Dos windows.
The command in comment is working fine, but with the runas it's an another think.

this is my script :

```
 ' WshShell.Run "C:\Down\XP\Install_TV_Cmd_Line.bat", SW_HIDE,true


Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
strcmd="""C:\Down\XP\Install_TV_Cmd_Line.bat"""
pass = "xxxxxx"
User = "xxxxxx\administrator"
Wshshell.run "runas.exe" & " /U:" & user & " " & strcmd
wscript.sleep(1000)
Wshshell.sendkeys pass & "{ENTER}"
```

How can i do for pass the SW_HIDE argument please ?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

to run the command line in hide mode with vbscript

```
Wshshell.run "runas.exe" & " /U:" & user & " " & strcmd, 0, False
```

0 Hide the window (and activate another window.)
 1 Activate and display the window. (restore size and position) when display a window for first time.
 2 Activate & minimize.
 3 Activate & maximize.
 4 Restore. The active window remains active.
 5 Activate & Restore.
 6 Minimize & activate the next top-level window in the Z order.
 7 Minimize. The active window remains active.
 8 Display the window in its current state. The active window remains active.
 9 Restore & Activate. Specify this flag when restoring a minimized window.
10 Sets the show-state based on the state of the program that started the application.